# How to import modules in python using importlib?

Tags: python, import, relative-import

I have this project structure:

> Scripts
>
> ```
> -- A
>     == AA
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ AAA.py
>         ++ AAB.py
>         ++ AAC.py
>     == AB
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ ABA.py
>         ++ ABB.py
>         ++ ABC.py
> -- B
>     == BA
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ BAA.py
>         ++ BAB.py
>         ++ BAC.py
>     == BB
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ BBA.py
>         ++ BBB.py
>         ++ BBC.py
> ```

I want to import classes inside `Scripts/A/AA/AAA.py` into `Scripts/B/BB/BBC.py`. I have used some solutions:

1. `from AAA import *` gives me `ImportError: No module named AAA`.
2. `from Scripts.A.AA.AAA import *` gives me `ImportError: No module named Scripts.A.AA.AAA`.
3. `from ..A.AA.AAA import *` gives me `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`.
4. `from ....A.AA.AAA import *` gives me `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

what should I do ?

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed the project's structure and now it's something like this:

> Scripts
>
> ```
> -- elements
>     == A
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ AAA.py
>         ++ AAB.py
>         ++ AAC.py
>     == B
>         ++ __init__.py
>         ++ BAA.py
>         ++ BAB.py
>         ++ BAC.py
> -- general
>     == imports.py
>     == __init__.py
> -- main.py
> ```

I have wrote this piece of code to import all classes:

```
elementDict = []
dirList = os.walk('elements') 
for dname in dirList:  
    fileList = dname[2]
    for fname in fileList:
        if fname != '__init__.py' and fname.endswith('.py') and (not fname.endswith('_ut.py')) and (not fname.endswith('~')):  
            path = dname[0].split(os.sep)
            path = filter(None, path[path.index('elements'):])
            dir = '.'.join(path)
            mod = importlib.import_module(dir + '.' + fname[:-3])
            for cname, obj in inspect.getmembers(mod, inspect.isclass): 
                if cname not in elementDict:  
                    elementDict[cname] = obj
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Scripts\general\imports.py", line 29, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(dir + '.' + fname[:-3])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named elements.A.AAA
```

Any idea?

**EDIT 2:**

I have resolved the problem; I did not have any `__init__.py` in `elements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) only work within a package structure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) for more detailed answers.

In this case `AA` and `BB` are two different packages, so the relative imports in 3 and 4 fail. `Scripts` isn't a package at all (neither are `A` or `B`), so 2 fails and since it's not likely, that you have `Scripts/A/AA` in your PYTHONPATH also 1 fails.

You need to have `Scripts/A` in your PYTHONPATH and then call `from AA.AAA import *`. If you already have `Scripts` in the PYTHONPATH, you could add a `Scripts/A/__init__.py` file to make the directory a python package and call `from A.AA.AAA import *` instead.

Comment: I checked the `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` and `Scripts` was there; but I got `No module named A.AA.AAA` for `from A.AA.AAA import *`.

Comment: I just saw, that  `A` isn't a package at all. How did you import the module `BB.BBC`?

Comment: I did not import it anywhere.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the actual structure of your project. Since `Scripts` is in your PYTHONPATH the second approach (adding `Scripts/A/__init__.py`) might be best suited for your.

Comment: Is there any other way than that which does not affect project structure?

Comment: Fiddling with the PYTHONPATH or any other import method with the [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) or the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module. You should update your question, explaining what you want to do or ask another one.